# Android | SQLLite : Pre-created database updating without using SQLiteOpenHelper

Tags: java, android, xml, sqlite, sql-update

My app uses a SQLite database for the information. I have a function that checks to see if the folder and database are already present, if they aren't it will go on the internet ( currently I am using dropbox to store the db file ) and download the database and store it on the sd card, then I it will open the database. The database is writable as it lets the user rate an object. I have two questions.

1.) I would love to provide updates to the database and then have my app update the database if the version number is higher and replace the existing one. I have done some research and from what I have found it is possible to store an xml or json file with the version number of and the just parse the information and if the version number is higher download the new database.

Can someone provide an example of how this is accomplished and whether it is better to use xml or json for this task?

2.) Is there a way to save the rating in the new version of the database when the new is downloaded and accessed?

Thanks

Comment: [SQLiteDatabase.html#setVersion(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#setVersion%28int%29) is what SQLiteOpenHelper uses to set the version. You could use that too. It's `PRAGMA user_version` if you want to do that from sqlite directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

two nights ago I wrote something like that.

- pack your database structure as an array in a webservice method by reading field names and field types. the structure of array is arbitrary.
- call web service method and you must receive a string that represent a JSONArray object, if you sent it as json with json_encode() method in php.
- read structure and make CREATE DB query string with for loops.
- execute query, so you must have database.
- also you can send alot of information with arrays.
- introducing each part is hard, so for each part google it.
- don't forget to convert field types to match SQLite types such as VARCHAR=>TEXT, smallint=>INTEGER , ...